# Applied for API Quota Increase, Quota decreased to 0

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I applied for a YouTube Data API quota increase, and now my quota was set to 0, without a word from YouTube.
Is this a glitch or intentional? Is YouTube upset at me?
Does anybody know a way to reach out to the API Quota department to discuss?

Comment: Now stackoverflow is upset at you too. (not really, but we can't answer subjective questions or recommend youtube's customer support for you)

Comment: @PeteKirkham The YouTube API team monitors this tag. My hope is that someone will let me know who I can get in touch with. I'm not sure why you are saying that "we can't recommend youtube's customer support for you". And possibly, someone had a similar experience and can share insight.

Comment: @Fomo ask in [Issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) instead - stack overflow are for qestions and answers about programming - your problem is with YouTube quota administration - out of the scope of this site. sorry.